What is the proper way of asking a question that seeks an explanation for a phenomenon that is believed to be real based on anecdotal evidence?
Questions seeking a scientific explanation for the asker's anecdotal experience has been asked before, with a very good reception by the community. For instance:

By learning to read and write upside down, what did I do to myself?
Does psychology have a name for emotions that a person can feel but cannot name?

In fact, I've also had my fair share of well-received questions that were inspired by anecdotal evidence. For example:

Is there a scientific explanation for dramatic body shaking and trembling in religious settings? (see videos for illustrative examples) (based on the anecdotal evidence of many audio-visual examples)
Explanation for the “spinal energy” and other “Kundalini awakening” symptoms? (based on many first-hand reports and a paper that in turn is also based on many first-hand reports)
Can someone be healed from a long-held addiction or compulsive disorder in an instant and without therapy due to a dramatic spiritual experience? (based on a couple of anecdotal reports)

Unfortunately, I didn't have the same luck with my last question: What are possible explanations for the ecstatic experience of “warm oil or honey poured over the top of head and slowly moving down”?
Just like with my previous questions, the idea of my last question didn't just "randomly" pop up in my mind, but was the result of noticing a clear pattern of experience after watching/reading many anecdotal reports. Why is my last question not enjoying the same luck as previous well-received anecdotal-evidence-based questions? In general, how should a question based on anecdotal evidence be asked in order to expect a good reception by the P&N community?

Related: “I have X, how common is X?”: self help question, or not?
